# a question about お預かりいたします

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

> また、通常の売買の際にも、釣り銭があるような場合に、「お預かりいたします」が用いられるようです。このような場面でも、受け取った金銭のすべてを所有するのでないという意味から、「いただきます」「頂戴します（頂戴いたします）」に替わって使用されているものと考えられます。
>
> ご指摘の「○○円からお預かりいたします」という表現は、文字どおりには「○○円から幾らかを一時的に保管します（受け取り手の所有するところとはなりません）」という意味ですから、会費の受け取りなどの際には用いられても、通常の売買の際には不適切な表現であるということができます。

so this was an answer for a question about  `円からお預かりいたします` and whether it is right or not but what i find confusing is that it says
that 「お預かりいたします」is used in every day life but then it says 「○○円からお預かりいたします」is 不適切な表現であるということができます meaning that it is inappropriate which i find confusing

Comment: The answer is explained in the text there... Is it just that you're having trouble understanding the explanation? What about it are you unsure of?

Comment: well, i am not sure what does he mean by 不適切な表現であるということができます here

Comment: You seemed to understand that bit. It can be said to be inappropriate. But your question seemed to be "why is it inappropriate" and that part is explained prior to that.

Comment: it did not explain though

Comment: You see this part という意味ですから What comes before that is an explanation of why it can be thought of as inappropriate.

Comment: i knew what you mean but  why it the case 受け取り手の所有するところとはなりません should not be inappropriate reason

Comment: The meaning doesn't match what happens in a typical retail transaction though. That's why it can be thought of as inappropriate...